# Use a for loop to display string values in symbols

Tags: python

I have a list `die_count = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`;
element 0 is not used so ignore that, elements 1-6 are important.
So basically the elements are connected to random.randint's that generate a random number and in my program, these numbers are generated multiple times upon user utilization.

So at the end of my program I need to show these statistics as such:

```
Dice Roll Stats:
Face Frequency
 1 *
 2 ***
 3 *
 4 *
 5 **
 6 **
```

So as you can see, the list is basically the sides of dice, and the stars show how many times that face had been generated during the program

I tried doing it like this but sometimes the code doesn't execute, sometimes it does and just shows integers.

```py
index = 1
while index < die_count[2] :
    for num in die_count :
        print(num)
        index += 1
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
die_count = [0,4,5,3,2,1,7]

for i in range(1, len(die_count)):
    print(i, die_count[i] * "*")
```

It will output:

```
1 ****
2 *****
3 ***
4 **
5 *
6 *******
```

In what cases does your code doesn't work? It isn't clear from the question.

Also why you initiate `die_count` with 7 elements if you don't use the first element. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why use two print statements? why not just ````print(i, die_count[i] * "*")````?

Comment: @7koFnMiP There is no reason, I changed it. Thanks.

Comment: Also maybe he does use the first element just not for the purpose of this code. StackOverflow questions only need to be reproducible

Comment: @7koFnMiP maybe, but he states "element 0 is not used so ignore that" this is why.

Comment: Thanks, this is working, however it doesn't always execute, sometimes it won't execute for some reason, I'll try pm'ing you

Comment: Hmm I'm unable to PM, how do I do that?

Comment: @DanyalKhan I'm not sure either. feel free to ask here.

Comment: Alright so basically the code works on some instances and others it doesn't execute at  all, 

`index = 1
while index < die_count[1] :
        for i in range(1, len(die_count)):
            print(i, die_count[i] * "*")

        index += 1`

I think there is something to do with the index part,

Comment: @DanyalKhan Why the `while` loop? What exactly you do with `index`?

Comment: Oh true David, before when I was trying to figure it out I thought I'd use it within the while loop I was working with, I have now removed it and it seems to be working perfectly! Thanks!!! I'll get back to you if something comes up

Comment: @DavidS so basically the values need to be added, as the numbers generate again and again if the user wishes to do so, it is working right now but does not add new values

Comment: @DanyalKhan so just wrap this code in a function, and call it whenever new values are present. You should write logic that does it.

Comment: @DavidS tHANKS, I've wrapped it within a function and it seems to be working fine, if it comes to an issue I shall return ahah

Answer (score 1):

you can also get a little more advanced and use this allows user input to decide the number of times a dice has rolled than displays it

```
side = 0
diceList = [0]
while side !=6:
    side +=1
    diceCount = int(input(f'How many times did the dice roll on side {side}: '))
    diceList.append(diceCount)
for i in range(1, len(diceList)):
    print(i, diceList[i] * "*")
```

Comment: did this and it worked as expected, even if you dont use it this can offer some new tricks or show you something you didnt think of, hope it helps